# Finding the limits in the order dydxdz

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I need help finding the limits to the triple integral: $$\iiint\limits_{E}{f(x,y,z)}\: dy\, dx\, dz$$ where $E$ is bounded by the plane, $2x+y=2$ and the cylinder, $z=y^2$.

I'm also having trouble visualizing what the graph looks like. If someone could help me out, that would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: The "cylinder" is not a cylinder, but a parabola extended along the x-axis.  When you solve the first equation for $y$, what happens when you plug that result in to the second equation?  Are there no other constraints on the area of integration?

Comment: @abiessu: Actually, "parabolic cylinder" is the correct term for the surface defined by $z=y^2$. It is fair to make sure the OP didn't actually mean (circular) cylinder, of course.

Comment: @Hurkyl: okay, I can buy that.  I've always hated terminology that allows this type of confusion...

Comment: Is the equation of the plane $2x+y=z$ instead of $2x+y=2$?

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment, but I need 50 reputation. Anyways, try drawing a diagram.

You'll see that it is bounded by the parabolic cylinder z = y^2, x being a free variable. The plane 2x + y = z bounds it from above.

Edit: I just saw it is 2x + y = 2. There are no bounds from the left side....

Comment: Note that the OP says $2x+y=2$, not $2x+y=z$.  Either way, this particular pairing is not able to define a closed area of integration, so I think the answer is positive infinity until we get more information.

Comment: I just saw that. I agree with you, unless he is referring to the first octant.